# How to make the two textviews invisible on the touch in android

Tags: android, multi-touch, textview

I have come up with an idea such that on the touch of the two TextViews both become invisible. This idea works when I touch a single finger on the TextView and only one TextView becomes invisible. But when I test it with two finger, only one Textview becomes invisible. It does not make both the textviews invisble.

I have written the following code.

```
public class MatchMeaning1 extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    private static final String TAG = MatchMeaning1.class.getSimpleName();

    TextView[] txtWord, txtMeaning;

    int [] wordID = {R.id.txtWord1, R.id.txtWord2, R.id.txtWord3, R.id.txtWord4, R.id.txtWord5};
    int[] meaningID = {R.id.txtMeaning1,R.id.txtMeaning2, R.id.txtMeaning3, R.id.txtMeaning4, R.id.txtMeaning5 };

    String[] word = {"1.abidcation","2.abhor","3.abide","4.abyssmal","5.award"};
    String[] meaning = {"a.deep","b.stay","c.cede","d.accolade","5.hate"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.match_meaning);
        txtWord = new TextView[5];
        txtMeaning = new TextView[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < txtWord.length; i++){
            txtWord[i] = (TextView)findViewById(wordID[i]);
            txtMeaning[i] = (TextView)findViewById(meaningID[i]);
            txtWord[i].setText(word[i]);
            txtMeaning[i].setText(meaning[i]);
            txtWord[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
            txtMeaning[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

        if(pointerCount == 2){
            TextView [] tv = new TextView[2];
            for(int i = 0; i < tv.length ;i++){
                tv[i] = (TextView)v;
                tv[i].setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The above code doesn't work for pointerCount = 2, but it works for pointerCount = 1. 
Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onTouch event is processed on a per view basis so it would be firing for both textviews except you're returning true which swallows the event. What you want is probably closer to:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(v != YOUR_TEXT_VIEW1 && v != YOUR_TEXT_VIEW2) return false;
    ((TextView)v).setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
    return false;
}
```

Replace YOUR_TEXT_VIEW 1 & 2 with objects you declare as the current two text views you want to disappear.

**EDIT:**

If you only want the views to disappear if the user is touching both of them you're going to have to devise a more involved approach. I see two possibilities:

1. The onTouch event needs to call another function which appends all views triggered by each unique MotionEvent. After appending the view to the list the function checks to see if both expected views are present. If so, trigger the invisibility calls.
2. Instead of using onTouch use the [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method and determine if the getX(index) getY(index) coordinates fall inside the two views you are expecting to be touched.

Comment: The above code is working for single touch only which is as good as pointerCount = 1. Your above mentioned code allows to point one finger at a time on a textview and makes it disappear. I want to disappear both textviews at once.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone does not support `multitouch`Event.That's why if you are touching two text view at a time, its taking only one event at a time and one `textview`became invisible.

so first check whether your phone support more then one touch at time.